# Problems with steam after playing games

Tags: 13.10, steam

I have a problem with my steam client here.I open steam and play a few hours of Dota2, but after I'm done.. it takes more than 5 minutes to close and slows down my overall system performance. Is there any way to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64bit and I'm also playing Dota 2 using Steam for Linux.

Could you please add some information to your question? It's unclear if Dota 2 or Steam take 5 minutes close and what exactly happens.

My best guess is that Steam says something like "Synchronizing Updates" what basically means that files are getting uploaded to SteamCloud.

If that's the case, you can simply right-click Dota 2 on the list, go to Properties > Updates > SteamCloud and uncheck Enable Steam Cloud.

Disabling SteamCloud means that if you're going to play Dota 2 from your account on another computer you won't have the files saved on your current computer, though Dota progress will be conserved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear with my problem. Its like when i first open Dota2.. it takes almost 4 minutes to start and another 3 to start a match after accepting a match. this always happens only on my first match.. the subsequent matches load relatively quickly.but when i quit the game.. my entire system is slowed down for some reason and it stays that way till i restart  the computer.. my computer configuration is enough to play the game at basic graphics.. so that's game play is not a problem